# INCONSISTENT_BEHAVIOR_CROSS_VERSION.PARSE_DATETIME_BY_NEW_PARSER

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks-sql

I am very new to pyspark and getting below error, even if drop all date related columns or selecting only one column. Date format stored in my data frame like "[image]". Can anyone please suggest changes I could made in dataframe to resolve this/date formats supported by new parser.
*It's working if I set "spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy" to "LEGACY"*

> [INCONSISTENT_BEHAVIOR_CROSS_VERSION.PARSE_DATETIME_BY_NEW_PARSER] You may get a different result due to the upgrading to Spark >= 3.0:
> Caused by: DateTimeParseException: Text '1/1/2023 3:57:22 AM' could not be parsed at index 0
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 15.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.3 in stage 15.0 (TID 355) (10.139.64.5 executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: [INCONSISTENT_BEHAVIOR_CROSS_VERSION.PARSE_DATETIME_BY_NEW_PARSER] You may get a different result due to the upgrading to Spark >= 3.0:
> Fail to parse '1/1/2023 3:57:22 AM' in the new parser. You can set "spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy" to "LEGACY" to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to "CORRECTED" and treat it as an invalid datetime string.

Example:

```
#spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

emp = [(1, "AAA", "dept1", 1000, "12/22/2022  3:11:44 AM"),
(2, "BBB", "dept1", 1100, "12/22/2022  3:11:44 AM"),
(3, "CCC", "dept1", 3000, "12/22/2022  3:11:44 AM"),
(4, "DDD", "dept1", 1500, "12/22/2022  3:11:44 AM"),
(5, "EEE", "dept2", 8000, "12/22/2022  3:11:44 AM"),
(6, "FFF", "dept2", 7200, "12/22/2022  3:11:44 AM"),
(7, "GGG", "dept3", 7100, "12/22/2022  3:11:44 AM"),
(8, "HHH", "dept3", 3700, "12/22/2022  3:11:44 PM"),
(9, "III", "dept3", 4500, "12/22/2022  3:11:44 PM"),
(10, "JJJ", "dept5", 3400,"12/22/2022 3:11:44 PM")]
empdf = spark.createDataFrame(emp, ["id", "name", "dept", "salary", 
"date"])

#empdf.printSchema()
df = empdf.withColumn("date", F.to_timestamp(col("date"), 
"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"))
df.show(12,False)
```

Thanks a lot, in Advance

Comment: Could you please add the sample data, the code which triggers this error and desired output?

Comment: Hi @BartoszGajda, Really sorry for late reply, I have added sample code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to share update on this, After updating `df = empdf.withColumn("date", F.to_timestamp(col("date"),  "MM/dd/yyyy  hh:mm:ss a"))` to `df = empdf.withColumn("date", F.to_timestamp(col("date"),  "M/d/yyyy h:m:s a"))` it's working for me.

Comment: In my case switching from `'MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss a'` to `'MM/d/yyyy H:mm:ss a'` made it work without the error. The date looks like this: 1/13/2020 1:11:34 AM

Answer (score 0):

Following settings worked for me:-
s

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")
```